# Yii2 full calendar custom button?

Tags: yii2, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add a custom button into yii2 full calendar, but doesn't work for me.

Basically, I want to include a button as part of the full calendar view, i.e., next to the month and date. This button should be to the left of the calendar header.

I'm using customButton from Full Calendar, but this doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Helpful : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/

Comment: Thanks, i doing it by this way ..But if i run it, it say Doesn´t know customButton class or something like that. I upgrade this version for yii2, but still not work. How i can implement it into this?                                              <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
          'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/worker/reports/jsoncalendar']),
          'id'=>'fc_user',
          
       
    
          'header' => [
          'left' => '',
          'center' => 'prev,title,next',
          'right' => 'today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          ],

Comment: Setting unknown property: yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::customButtons

Comment: Still doesnť work with this documentantion.  Any other help? -.-

Comment: Probably can help, but more information is needed. Firstly, what extension are you trying to use? There are lots of full calender extension. Which one? Is there a link to the source code? What have you tried so far? What do you mean, 'it doesn't work'? Can you be a bit more specific. 'It doesn't work' could mean anything from the button not appearing, an incorrect response, page not found error, server error or anything. What do you mean? Please edit your question with more information!

Comment: I using yii 2 actually. I tried to do similar method of use from documentantion. But the debug says following : <code> yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::customButtons </code>  In my code i use this: <code> customButtons: [
        'cars'=> [
            'text': =>'cars',
           
        ]
    ],
   'header' => [
          'left' => 'cars',
          'center' => 'prev,title,next',
          'right' => 'today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          ], </code> I cant still figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Support for customButtons is supported in version 2.4.0. Make sure you're using this version or higher.